# Javascript/jQuery slowdown when switching to full screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, fullscreen

I have some strange behavior from firefox, I'm building a single page portfolio and as a graphic designer the coding has been hard. I wanted to smoothly control the navigation and then later added scaling to all the elements (designed for 1920x1080 full screen initially). The lecturer dropped a bomb that it needed to scroll vertically as well, I am in the process of trying to get the vertical navigation to work.

The issue is when I switch to full screen most of the navigation code seems to take a long pause before it executes. This only happens when I switch to full screen. If I switch and refresh then it's ok. I really want to know whats slowing the whole thing down.

I have tried safe mode with no plugins. I'm using Firefox 24.0 with Firebug to get at the bits an pieces.

I have created a code fiddle (my first and it's already broken):
http://jsfiddle.net/jeffreyknipe/xfjmC/1/

The code for the scrolling is as follows:

```
    function navTo(horizontal, vertical) {
        browserWidth = $(window).innerWidth();
        browserHeight = $(window).innerHeight();
        newRatio = browserWidth / 1920;

        $('html body div#full_site section#pages_section').animate({
            marginLeft: '-' + browserWidth * horizontal,
            marginTop: (browserWidth / 16 * 9) * vertical
        }, 1000);
        if (horizontal == 0) {
            $('#menuspace #floating_topbar #menuzone').animate({
                marginRight: 0
            });
        } else {
            $('#menuspace #floating_topbar #menuzone').animate({
                marginRight: (newRatio * (-340))
            });
        };
    };
```

I know the coders out there will frown on how inefficient the code is but any advice will be appreciated. The biggest thing is the full screen code slow down.

Thanks.

Comment: One thing you can try to speed things up is get rid of `html` and `body` on your selector since all elements will have them as parents. Then you can try getting rid of `div` in `div#full_site` and `section` in `section#pages_section` since IDs are unique, and you should not need to be more specific (unless you're purposefully trying to increase its specificity). For the same reason, you should be able to get rid of `#full_site` and both instances of `#menuspace #floating_topbar` unless you're specifically targeting between separate pages. This should decrease the amount of checks they'll need.

Answer (score 0):

The issue came in when animating the changes in items or location when going to and from full screen. I switched to setting the new values with .css rather than .animate (I did want it to animate to the new location) but since animation here wasn't a deal breaker and it solved the issue I'm a happy camper.

I have to assume that it wants to animate but the java script engine or some thing in Firefox get too busy during the change, it's almost a bug but I can't isolate whats happening while the script is jammed so I can't report it.